# Rails - Beginner. Sending JSON to Rails, updating it and sending back new JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Rails application that needs to retrieve data from a SOAP server outside of my control. It retrieves a list of users with statistics attached to them and returns the data as JSON.

Once that data is retrieved, I need to combine it with data retrieved from my Rails app database.

Once I have the JSON from the SOAP server in hand, I send it up to a Rails controller so that new values can be added to the JSON and then sent back to the view.

My problem is a very simple one. I can't seem to *read* and iterate through the JSON once it's in my controller.

**JS from my view** stat_data is the JSON received from the SOAP service

```
window.get_metrics = (stat_data) ->
    update_loading_message 'Getting Metrics'
     console.log stat_data

    $.ajax '/tracking/get_metrics',
        type: "POST"
        data: client_data: stat_data
        dataType: 'json'
        success : (data) ->
            console.log(data)
            # populate_table(data)
```

**Controller**

```
@client_advisors = params[:client_data]
puts @client_advisors

# This is where I would do my other processing / model calls to get new data

render file: 'tracking/metrics_data.json.erb', content_type: 'application/json'
```

**Output of `puts @client_advisors`**

```
{
"0"=>
{
"personnel_id"=>"1495", 
"personnel_name"=>"John Smith",
"statistic_x"=>"200"
}, 
"1"=>
{
"personnel_id"=>"5266",
"personnel_name"=>"John Candy",
"statistic_x"=>"300"
},
"2"=>{
... etc ...
}
}
```

**tracking/metrics_data.json.erb**

```
[
<%= puts '~~~~~~~~~~~~  PROCESSING JSON' %>
<% @client_advisors.each do |advisor| %>

<%= puts 'advisor::' %>
<%= puts advisor %>
<%= puts 'advisor.inspect::' %>
<%= puts advisor.inspect %>
{   
... This is where my re-generated JSON would go

}
<% end %> 
]
```

I ridiculously can't seem to target a personnel_name or personnel_id in my metrics_data.json.erb. It's outputting each full advisor object just fine in the console... But I'm not sure what I should be using to target the object's values. I've tried `advisor.personnel_name` (obviously won't work because the objects are named "0, 1, 2, etc"), `advisor['0']`, `advisor[0]`, `advisor[:0]`. None allow me to go a level deeper and retrieve the personnel_name.

Your time is most appreciated!

### Solved!

Thanks to @willglynn

"jQuery – somewhat surprisingly – has no mechanism to create JSON. It can parse just fine, but you have to encode it yourself. You can use JSON.stringify , but for *ahem* certain browsers, you need JSON2.js" - @willglynn

**Updated JS**

```
window.get_metrics = (stat_data) ->
    update_loading_message 'Getting Metrics'
     console.log stat_data

    $.ajax '/tracking/get_metrics',
        type: "POST"
        data: client_data: JSON.stringify(stat_data)
        dataType: 'json'
        success : (data) ->
            console.log(data)
            # populate_table(data)
```

**Updated controller**

```
@client_advisors = JSON.parse(params[:client_data])
```

**Updated tracking/metrics.erb.json**

```
<% puts advisor %>
<% puts advisor['personnel_id'] %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, when Rails gets a `POST` of JSON content, it transforms the request content into something looking like a form submission. This means that `params[]` won't exactly match the original object. To get the original object back, you need to go behind Rails' back and parse it out of the request directly:

```
@client_advisors = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read)
```

That said, there are a number of things I would change about this code.

- You have a SOAP server that returns JSON, and this is somehow getting *sent* to your Rails app. What component does that? Why? Could you cut out the middleman and make Rails talk directly to the SOAP component?
- You're generating JSON with string concatenation in an `erb` template. This is error-prone and tedious. Instead, use `render :json => [{ 'key' => 'value' }]`.
- You're putting lots of knowledge into the view. This is a normal place to start, but it's not ideal. I would probably make a model that encapsulates the response from this SOAP component -- not ActiveRecord, just a Ruby object -- and make that model responsible for interacting with my other models to have the desired effects.

That last one is important, since it would let you eliminate your view and reduce the controller to something like:

```
@soap_thing = CrazySoapThing.parse(request.body.read)
@soap_thing.sync
render :json => @soap_thing.affected_records
```

See [Skinny Controller, Fat Model](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) for more.

Comment: 1. I have all interactions with the client's SOAP server handled in its own controller. My view first needs to request data from this service and verify that any data exists. Then I'm sending JSON back to Rails to add more data. 2. The reason I'm using erb is because I've only shown a small sample of the data. There will actually be 26 values per advisor. 3. Can you explain 'putting a lot of knowledge into the view?' The view is a few dropdowns that filter the type of data requested from the client server and a submit button. JSON received, JSON sent, JSON received and displayed in a table.

Comment: But I do get what you're saying about creating a Ruby object that's responsible for interacting with other models.

Comment: Yeah, that's really what it's about. Views should worry about formatting data... but for JSON, there's nothing to format besides the data itself, so `render :json => data` is sufficient. Controllers are to control models, which could mean micro-managing everything, but it's better to ask the models to do what you want rather than to tell them how to do it. Models are where most of your business logic should live, and especially anything concerned with the actual, concrete representation of data.

Comment: Using `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read)` is throwing the error `756: unexpected token at 'client_data%5B0%5D%5Bpersonnel_id%5D=0&client_data%5B0%5D%5Bpersonnel_name%5D=John+Smith&client_data%5B0... etc etc (the whole json object)`

Comment: Ah, so it *is* a form submission, not a JSON post. Please update the question.

Comment: *Shouldn't* it be a JSON post? Why isn't it? Updated question to show the jQuery.ajax() post.

Comment: jQuery – somewhat surprisingly – has no mechanism to create JSON. It can parse just fine, but you have to encode it yourself. You can use `JSON.stringify` , but for *ahem* certain browsers, you need [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Answer (score 1):

`@client_advisors` is just a String, you have to parse it first:

```
@client_advisors = JSON.parse(params[:client_data])
@client_advisors['0']['personnel_name'] #=>"John Smith"
```

You should also have a look at [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) ([Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl)).

---

Btw.: `<%= puts foo %>` is not a good practice, since `<%=` is for designated outputs. If you *have to* print debug data use `<% logger.debug { foo.inspect } %>` or use a proper debugger (`gem 'debugger'`)

Comment: `params[:client_data]` is clearly not a string given the `puts` output in the question. Presumably the requester is POSTing JSON as a request body, which Rails will parse into a parameters hash.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe it's a string. I had also tried `JSON.parse(params[:client_data])` and I get `can't convert ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String`

Comment: `<% puts advisor.kind_of?(Array) %>` outputs `true`... Why is it an array?

Comment: So what happens when you add <%= @client_advisors['0']['personnel_name']%> to your view

Comment: @JonDay even when I do `<% puts advisor['0'] %>` I get an error in my controller: `can't convert String into Integer`